# How do I access a shared network folder which requires authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, shared

I have a network shared folder and I want to access that folder from my asp.net mvc application.

It works fine on local but when I deploy it on the server it fails

Folder is user and password protected

The question is how to configure application to pass the authentication

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the folder is not local to the web server, I believe you need to setup delegation as described here: [How to configure an ASP.NET application for a delegation scenario](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810572).